# Why does the Visual Studio Code editor launch another terminal named code when I run javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

Everytime I run a `javascript` code, a new terminal gets created. I would so much prefer this not to happen and just make use of my default terminal which is `PowerShell`.
In a nutshell this is how my workspace has been configured:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Windows PowerShell": {
            "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
        }    
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": false,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
}
```

What I tried is;

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "clear; cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "clear; cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
}
```

I expected the code to work with my default terminal PowerShell but it still created another terminal named code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the **Code Runner extension** in Visual Studio Code, and you want to run JavaScript code in your default PowerShell terminal instead of creating a new terminal named "code."

You can achieve this by configuring the Code Runner extension to run the code in the integrated terminal. Make sure the "code-runner.runInTerminal" setting is set to false. Also, you can remove the "code-runner.executorMap" configuration for JavaScript, as it's not necessary to specify a custom executor for JavaScript.

By setting **"code-runner.runInTerminal": false**, Code Runner should now execute JavaScript code in the integrated terminal instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Well, the problem with the above is my feedback shows on the output tab, yet the program I'm running takes input from the user. This is not possible with "code-runner.runInTerminal" set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on this;
[In VSCode, Python debugger launches a new Terminal every time I debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194880/in-vscode-python-debugger-launches-a-new-terminal-every-time-i-debug/58194881#58194881)

It was made for python but also worked for me. I need a launch.json file with the configurations as below;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Javascript: new1.js",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["&&", "exit"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps the next javascript user.